# Positive potential is due to lack of electrons?

Tags: charge, potential

If electric charges are the only ones that can produce an electric field then a positive potential is produced by positive charges or a lack of electrons, is this true? If this is so, how can I calculate how much charge there is at a certain potential?

Answer (score 1):

It is not significant to talk about positive potential.  You can say that the potential at one point  is positive relative to that at another point.  This can result from many different distributions of charge, positive or negative.  When dealing with spherical charges it is customary to set the reference point very far away. Then the potential will be positive at an reasonable distance from any positive charge.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, a lack of electrons does not create a positive potential. However, the idea is not unfounded.

One should consider a group of electrons, imagine there are two groups one with 3 electrons and one with 5. The group with 3 has a charge of $-4.8E-19$c  and the other $8E-19$c. They both are negative regardless of the amount. The conclusion and point I am attempting to illustrate is that electrons are fundamentally negative in charge and can never create a positive electric field.

Where you and most people would get the idea that a lack of electron is really a positive, is in the fact that atoms are typically neutral. Hence to create positive ion, one does not add the positive particle, the proton, as that would change the element (although that new element would be a positive ion), they remove electrons (which is much easier to do and in electrolytic chemistry this is known as oxidation). Therefore the net charge then is overall positive.

As for how to calculate a potential there is the equation $u_e=qV$ where $u_e$ is electric potential, $q$ is the charge and $V$ the voltage in joules/coulomb.

Also, have an amazing day

-Riley W. McNamara Cook